# Can we reduce redundancy between two subqueries in an update statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

From Database System Concepts

> Suppose we have a relation funds_received(dept_name, amount) that
>   stores funds_received (say, by electronic funds transfer) for each of
>   a set of departments. Suppose now that we want to add the amounts to
>   the balances of the corresponding department budgets. In order to use
>   the SQL update statement to carry out this task, we have to perform a
>   look up on the funds received relation for each tuple in the
>   department relation. We can use subqueries in the update clause to
>   carry out this task, as follows: We assume for simplicity that the
>   relation funds received contains at most one tuple for each
>   department.
>
> ```
> update department set budget = budget +
> (select amount
> from funds_received
> where funds_received.dept_name = department.dept_name)
> where exists(
> select *
> from funds_received
> where funds_received.dept_name = department.dept_name);
> ```
>
> Note that the condition in the where clause of the update ensures that
>   only accounts with corresponding tuples in funds received are updated,
>   while the sub-query within the set clause computes the amount to be
>   added to each such department.

I was wondering why we need the `where` clause to first check if a department has any fund received?

The two subqueries are basically the same, and seem redundant.

Can't the following without the `where` clause work the same?

```
 update department set budget = budget +
 (select amount
 from funds_received
 where funds_received.dept_name = department.dept_name)
```

If a department doesn't have any received fund, then `amount` will be null, and `budge + ...` will not work?

I am interested in solutions in either SQL standard or PostgreSQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `where` clause in case nothing matches.  If so, then the `set` condition (as written) will return `NULL` -- probably a bad thing.

But Postgres has a better solution, using `from`:

```
update department d
    set budget = d.budget + fr.amount
from funds_received fr
where fr.dept_name = d.dept_name;
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) Does using `from` solve the problem in case that `fr.amount` is NULL? (2) in `set` and `where` clauses, can we add `d.` and drop it arbitrarily? For example, can `budget` and `d.budget` be arbitrarily exchanged? Can `dept_name` and `d.dept_name` be arbitrarily exchanged?

Comment: (3) Does  `from` create a cross product between `d` and `fr`?

Comment: @Ben . . . If `fr.amount` is `NULL`, then any solution with simple addition will set `budget` to `NULL`.  You need `coalesce()`.   You should qualify all column names in a query that has more than one table reference.  No, Postgres has an optimizer.  This is just Postgres's way of expressing a join in an update.

Comment: "No, Postgres has an optimizer." to (2) or (3)?  "This is just Postgres's way of expressing a join in an update", so do you mean `from` is to create a cross product between d and fr?

Comment: @Ben . . . Saying that is misleading.  There is a `WHERE` clause that defines the relationship between the table.  Postgres is not generating a cross product.  Conceptually, the query can be interpreted as a filtering on the cross product, but I'm not sure that's useful.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry. Are the `from` and `where` clauses to generate a join?

Comment: @Ben . . . That is the effect that they have in an update.

Answer (score 1):

You might leave the outer `WHERE` clause if you handle `NULL`s e.g. with `coalesce()`.

```
UPDATE department
       SET budget = budget
                    +
                    coalesce((SELECT amount
                                     FROM funds_received
                                     WHERE funds_received.dept_name = department.dept_name), 0);
```

That makes sure, if an department didn't receive any funds, there is no `NULL` returned which might make the addition yield `NULL` also (it might depend on the DBMS, what happens in such a case). The `coalesce()` will turn `NULL` to `0`, the neutral element of addition, so leaving the budget as it is.

(Assuming, that `funds_received.amount` cannot ever be `NULL`. If it was `NULL` the `coalesce()` cannot "know", if the `NULL` is there because no record was found or because the `amount` actually was `NULL`. In the case the `amount` is actually `NULL`, the original query will add `NULL` to the budget, my query will add a `0`. So the queries weren't equivalent in this case. But I think it's very likely the author of the book had such an implicit `NOT NULL` constraint on `funds_received.amount` in mind.)

But on the other hand, the `WHERE` clause might reduce the rows, that have to be updated (even if the update effectively doesn't change the value, the rows need to be read and written back) and therefore benefit performance.

Comment: As a note:  This doesn't do the same thing if `amount` s ever `NULL` in a matching row.  That is unlikely to be the case for this data, but it is worth understanding.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Valid point! Thanks. I added this to the answer.